# Get raw data pointer from empty std::vector

Tags: c++, c++03

This is an undefined behavior:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int const * a = &v[0];
```

My goal is to avoid the UB and the `vector::data()` function would work. But I need to do it without `>=C++11`.

For example, if I were to allocate some memory with `vector::reserve`, would it work?

```
v.reserve(1);
int const * a = &v[0];
```

Clarification:

The vector is not changed after the point I take the pointer and the vector may be empty or contain data.

Comment: Can't you do a ternary check on the `v.size()` and have a "backup" int somewhere? Like `v.size() ? &v[0] : &dummy`

Comment: reserve() is ok, but resize() would be even better.

Comment: @xanatos : that's a nice one...

Comment: Be careful that once you have the raw pointer, any operation that causes an internal reallocation (e.g. `push_back`) will result in an invalidated dangling pointer.

Comment: Just wanted to write the same.... How can this pointer ever be useful if it points to non-existant storage and will (probably) be invalidated when the first element is added?

Comment: @user1095108 `resize()` would change the vector (when not empty), that's unexpected.

Comment: `reserve` will do the same thing if it does not have enough capacity.

Comment: @Jahid not necessarily, as you probably know. It's homework for the OP.

Comment: @CoryKramer : vector data after that point is not changed..

Comment: @user1095108 : `resize(): Resizes the container to contain count elements.

If the current size is greater than count, the container is reduced to its first count elements. `

Comment: @Jahid how about `v.resize(v.size() + 1)`? We're just nitpicking, as I wrote, homework for the OP.

Comment: @user1095108 did you notice that you're discussing this with OP himself? ;)

Comment: @user1095108 : and why would I want to increase the size (even for 1) when the vector is not empty?, that's nonsense...

Comment: @Jahid Some people have very strict requirements about avoiding UB at all costs. resize(), as well as reserve() both serve to accomplish that. I thought UB was the primary concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just perform the check inside a conditional operator:

```
int const * a = v.empty() ? NULL : &v[0];
```

This has the added benefit over `data()` that you can check from the pointer itself whether the vector was empty: if it was, `a` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors don't provide any guarantees of the pointers of their elements. It's very dangerous to use that reserve you did, because you may `push_back()` some element later, which may invalidate your pointer.

If you want a better story, consider that even iterators may be invalidated with [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)... why would a pointer still remain valid at all?

Comment: Um, if there is no difference between storing a pointer and storing a iterator, why is using an iterator better?

Comment: @NathanOliver Because the standard doesn't provide any constraints on how pointers have to behave, AFAIK. However, it provides how iterators have to behave.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist of course it does. Iterator vs pointer only comes into play when you have a special non-random access iterator.

Comment: It says iterators and references are invalidate and since a reference is a pointer it is covered.  Anything that invalidates an iterator will invalidate the pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, sure. But what I'm saying is that there's no guarantee that a pointer will remain valid, even if the iterator is.

Comment: I removed the last part anyway. I gotta verify the picture I have in my mind about iterators vs pointers.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist you should go and build a thorium reactor, what's the use of quantum mumbo jumbo?

Comment: @user1095108 Because my PhD is in physics (particle physics), and yet I'm a software developer :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist you should build it while you're still young, you'll become a celebrity overnight. Then write a book and you're set for life.

Comment: @user1095108 Funnily enough, I'm writing a book "programming for scientists"... if I ever remain with the descipline to finish it xD

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Don't forget about life, SE Asia, build reactor there :)

Comment: @user1095108 Meh... I guess asia has more experts than I ever can be. Cheers!